# process incoming mail and parse out original text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have inherited a rails forum (Rails 2.3.2 I think) that alerts people of new posts/replies for the forums or threads they are watching.
To make it easier for people to answer to threads I would like to enable reply-to-post, similar to basecamp and a bunch of other forums and tools out there.
I would add a separator text (like "----add your reply above this line-----") in the original email.
I need to:

- process incoming email
- extract the new text (above the separator line) as plain text
- ideally strip out text like "on ... forums@mysite.com wrote:" that is automatically added by some mail clients
- identify the thread this email is referring to (either using the incoming address or the subject line)
- identify the sender
- post the content as new reply

Any suggestions on how to get started? Any good plugins for this?
I've seen many mentioning Mailman and Fetcher, are there any other and which one is the best for this little feature?

Thanks!

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/313-receiving-email-with-mailman

Comment: is there a version that is not paid to watch?

Comment: look at the gem documentation

Comment: yes I would, it fits your needs